# connection string in ADO.NET entity data model

Tags: connection-string, app-config, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a C# console application (say Project.Console) in which I am using a dll of another project (say Project.Data, which is a class library using ADO.NET Entity Data Model to retrieve data from the DB).

I have added the connection string in Project.Data's App.Config file. When I'm trying to access DB in Project.Console by the classes in dll an error (ArgumentException : 'The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.') is showing.

When I tested by adding the connection string in Project.Console's App.Config file also, its working fine.

Why its so? **Is it necessary to pass the connection string in  Project.Console's App.Config file since no direct DB interaction is there?**

From my learning, its only need to pass the connection string in Project.Data's App.Config file.. Am I right..?

Answer (score 0):

**the connection string is properly set in the DLL's app.config file.**

// Assumsing 
connectionString is your connectionString
ModelEntities context=new ModelEntity(connectionString, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

or like this:
1. The model is inside a folder called Models
2. The name of the library is ClassLibrary1
3. The name of the EF model is ClassLibrary1Model
4. connectionString is your connectionString

If you put the model lets in a folder called Model for example:
ModelEntities context=new ModelEntity(GetConnection("ClassLibrary1", "Models", "ClassLibrary1Model", connectionString));

Comment: I have the connection string in Project.Data App.Config file is as follows :    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="testEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TestEntity.csdl|res://*/TestEntity.ssdl|res://*/TestEntity.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source="datasource";initial catalog=testDB;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>